# How do I increase the width of a navbar dropdown?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm using bootstrap and trying to put a search form inside a navbar dropdown menu, but I'm finding the form looks squashed because the width of the dropdown is too small. Also, the form elements are not how I would like. How do I fix this?

I'm new to CSS and web design in general. Please help!

Current layout:

[image: current layout screenshot]

What I'm trying to achieve:

[image: desired layout screenshot]

```
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Browse</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Locate <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
              <div class="form-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn"><li class="icon-screenshot"></li></button>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address">
              </div>
              <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </form>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">USER <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-upload"></i> Link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-signout"></i> Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu { width: yourwidth }
```

You can add `display: inline-block`  so that its width will be according to its content automatically

Comment: Thanks, I added that and the width is now larger. If I added display: inline-block though, the dropdown menu was permanently visible. No problem though, I found that by putting the form items into separate divs with class="form-group" seemed to get them to display nicely.

Comment: The display: inline-block also displaying the drop down menu permanently on my application came as a surprise. I drop it.

Comment: apply it on .open class to prevent having it penitently.

Comment: `.open` means something like `.navbar-nav>.dropdown-menu.open`

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the "min-width" value in the dropdown.less

or make a new line in the css

```
.dropdown-menu { min-width: 200px }
```